# Default Value Pre-selected - Spring select

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, user-interface

I am using Spring's select path tag to render a drop down at the front end with data coming in from back end. Now, I want to select a default value at the front end without doing any changes at the controller. How can I do it?

Example-

```
<form:select path="country" items="${countryList}" />
```

The countries list coming in from the back end is "Select a Value", "US", "UK", "India", "Germany" etc.
Now, depending on the user's home country, I want to pre-select the country, say suppose Germany when the page loads up. How can I handle it at front end?

Comment: Is the `country` property already set in controller? Or do you want to decide the user's home country on client side?

Comment: I want to handle the value in front end. The list is populating as such. Can I do it at the tag level itself or do I have to use JQuery for manipulation?